# Collect dependencies with gradle android plugin

Tags: android, gradle

Is it possible to collect all dependencies into one place as jar-files in Gradle Android project?

I tried to use: [Gradle: collect application dependencies](https://coderwall.com/p/1jcnfa)

But Gradle returns error:

```
Could not find property 'testRuntime' on configuration container.
```

Comment: "Is it possible to collect all dependencies into one place as jar-files in Gradle Android project?" -- no, insofar as not all dependencies are JAR files. They might be AAR files or other artifacts.

Comment: Is it possible to collect all artifacts in one place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well testRuntime is a configuration that's seems not to be available in your project. to collect all configurations in a single folder you can do something like this:

```
task collectJars(type: Copy){
    into "$buildDir/output/lib"
    configurations.all{ config ->
        from config
    }
}
```